# I'm trying to validate pdf/a on a php form

Tags: php, forms, validation, pdfa

I've alredy built the form and the code for validating wheter or not it is a pdf file, but since i'm working on a school we need to have a pdf/a validation on the form. I'm serching but havent foung answears yet

Answer (score 0):

A PDF/A document can be identified as such through PDF/A-specific metadata located in the "http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/id/" namespace. This metadata represents a claim of conformance.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/A